# TimeMachine backup over DDNS AFP Causes Consistency Issue

Tags: network, backup, time-machine, afp

I have a TimeMachine backup to a local NFS (1Tb partition) on a WdMyBookEX2. The backup works fine when I'm connected locally over ethernet/wifi (takes a while to backup about a TB).

When I'm away from home, I have setup DDNS, port-forwarding for AFP, etc. So I can connect to my WDMyBookEX2 remotely over AFP and run the backups normally.

[image: Connect to drive AFP]

I typically add it as a '2nd Volume' in the prompt from the TimeMachine wizard.

However, I've discovered that *typically* after the verification of the backup is done, the wizard reports that it has "become inconsistent", and that TimeMachine suggests I start a 'new backup' in order to ensure consistency. (Don't have message in front of me right now)

[image: Select Disk]

[image: Use Both]

Is there anyway to avoid this? I would prefer to continue running backups while I'm away from home, even remotely.

Comment: That's because the host is part of the time machine connection reference, even if it's the same server.

Comment: @John Keates, so I should do the initial backup (say locally over lan)  to my afp disk and it should resolve the issue?

Comment: No, the issue is with using two different connections to the same share. Always use the same to resolve the issue.

Comment: Will this issue continue if my IP address isn't static? Hostname stays the same but I'm issued a new IP address by my ISP? I finished the backup always using the same hostname- however, I got the error again

Comment: Any change in the parameters will cause TimeMachine to loose track on who's who I'm afraid.